# Python POST запрос на форму сайта

Tags: python-3.x, post, requests

Пытаюсь сформировать POST-запрос на сайт с целью найти по форме нужную информацию. У формы куча полей, чекбоксов и т.д. (сайт по поиску недвижимости). В документации нашел примерно такой вариант:

```
import requests
url = 'https://realt.by/rent/business/search/'
text = {'#tx_uedboffice_pi2': 'Минск', '#tx_uedboffice_pi2':'checked'}
r = requests.post(url, data=text)
with open('test.html', 'w') as output_file:
  output_file.write(r.text)
```

При открытии test.html показывает форму, т.е. запросы не сработали.
Что я не так делаю? К слову в качестве ключей я взял name соответствующего input (select). Также в 1-м поле выпадающий список.
Очень прошу помочь!

---

Вечер добрый!
Спасибо большое!
Selenium помог сделать поиск, результат уже есть, но как дальше извлекать текст из таблицы с результатом нигде не нахожу. Я так понял Selenium сделан заменить тестировщика и верифицирует правильно ли отрабатывает программа, но не работает с полученным результатом

Comment: На какой странице находится форма? https://domain.by/rent/business/search/ возвращает (по крайней мере, мне) ошибку 404

Comment: Да, извините, вот адрес: https://realt.by/rent/business/search/

Comment: Боюсь, для каждого запроса нужно будет заполнять и добавлять в заголовок запроса вот сколько полей: https://prnt.sc/maogop . Можете изучить, как происходит отправка формы на этом сайте (ctrl+shift+i (chrome) -> network -> отправьте форму -> нажмите на первую запись в network'e). можете пробовать повторять запрос уже средствами python'a, добавляя необходимые заголовки и form-data. также есть вариант использования selenium и хром-вебдрайвера, но он мне не кажется значительно проще (https://duo.com/decipher/driving-headless-chrome-with-python )

Comment: можете попробовать сделать запрос, добавляя в form-data только те поля, у которых есть значение, а пустые пропускать, и посмотреть, как на это отреагирует сервер